# Why does putting an id attribute inside an input tag make the field required?

Tags: php, html

I have an html form, in a php (PHP 5.4.16) file. Some fields req'd others not. As the code stands, this is being enforced with an id attribute:

```
#barfs if you leave blank
<input type="text" size="30" name="tissue" id="tissue" value="">

#now its optional 
<input type="text" size="30" name="tissue" value="">
```

I've been googling, but the keywords are so generic I've had no luck. id isn't even mentioned as a possible attribute here:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

- I'd like to understand why the id attribute has this effect.
- Any documentation links also greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

(I'm aware that there's an much clearer 'required' attribute, but I'm trying to understand this legacy code before hacking away at it.)

EDIT:

Doh! Thanks everybody! There were a couple .js scripts which weren't loaded into my vi buffers, incuding.... :

```
checkEmptyField = function(id){
  var field = document.getElementById(id);
    if(field.value == "" ||  field.value == " "){
        document.getElementById(id).select();

        return "Field : " + field.name + " cannot be empty! \n";

    }else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Going by just your title and code provided, it doesn't. If it is, then you have something elsewhere, JS or perhaps PHP that is doing validation, but since you've only provided HTML, that's all we can say.

Comment: Thanks for responding! The error message popup, "Field: tissue cannot be empty!" seems to execute without calling any downstream code.  The string, "cannot be empty" is nowhere in the code.  

When I removed the id="tissue", it accepted a blank entry, and a NULL was written into the MYSQL table.

Comment: That it's doing it when ID is set suggests that there is some JS that's doing it. Either way what you're describing isn't an HTML feature, you'll just need to find the relevant code.

Comment: I guess you are using a template or some kind of framework. You need to either use a different ID for that input or find the JavaScript file with an unsubmit event that checks if the input ID has a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the full code you will find that the particular ID your using has been set to make/set it's input field to `required` this is most likely done on the JavaScript's part of the script or the php part take time to find it or use inspect elements (F12 on google Chrome) to see whats happing exactly.

Solution: either use a different ID or find where the DOM manipulation code lies and edit to desired result